# Prove that if $\lim_{t_0\to T}x(t)$ and $\lim_{t_0\to T}x'(t)$ exist, then x is differentiable on $[t_0,T]$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Problem assumes that $x$ is differentiable from $[t_0,T)$

The problem sounds like it wants me to use the MVT to prove that the existence of $\lim_{t_0\to T}x'(t)$ means that the function is differentiable on the closed interval, but analysis has never Beene my strong suit.

Does it suffice to say that $\lim_{t_0\to T}x'(t)$ is similar to $f'(c)$ in the Mean Value theorem, thus the interval $(a,b)$ from the definition of the MVT extends further than $[t_0,T]$ and thus x is differentiable on the closed interval?

Comment: Actually the conclusion should be $x$ *extends* to be differentiable on $[t_0,T].$ I also think the assumption $\lim x(t)$ exists is not needed.

Comment: This is false: consider $x(t)=t^2$ for $0\le t<1$ and $x(1)=42$. Then the limits $\lim_{t\to 1}x(t)$ and $\lim_{t\to 1}x'(t)$ both exist, but the function is not differentiable at $1$.